# Why must I run automation test cases on windows?

Tags: ui-automation, cypress

I have been told that I must run my automation test cases on win10 platform and Chrome.
Our project is based on Chorme Browser.
I am confused ,because we write cases on MacOs,and we could have ran the cases on linux server.
We are using Jenkins+Cypress+Chrome to do automation test.On MacOS,it works well;but when I move the codes to win10,I must modify codes to adapt win10，and I have to solve bugs that never happened on Mac OS.
Are there any different between Linux+Chrome and Windows+Chrome？
Is it necessary for us to run automation test cases on Windows？

Comment: Addition: Our costomer's computers are win10 platform

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary for us to run automation test cases on Windows？

No, Cypress can run on several operating systems (including Windows, Linux and MacOS). So there is no need to specifically run the test on a Windows 10 system.

For the browsers you are limited to Chrome and Electron.

> Are there any different between Linux+Chrome and Windows+Chrome?

Yes there are differences, for example shortcut key combo's, but there are multiple differences.

> I have been told that I must run my automation test cases on win10
>   platform and Chrome.

Who did tell you that? Without a source or more information about the why we can't help you with that question.